# Approximating a characteristic function and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x) = \chi_{[0, 1)}$. Is there a sequence of smooth functions $f_{n}$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}'(t)|\, dt \rightarrow 0$ and $\|f_{n} - f\|_{L^{1}} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the harder question is to assume $\int_{\mathbb R} |f_n'| dx \to 0$. Because if you only assume $\int_0^1 |f_n'|dx \to 0$, you can choose $f_n$ constant in $(0,1)$ (and such a sequence can be found).

For the harder question, I will show indirectly that such a sequence does not exist. Let $\phi$ be any smooth function which is zero outside a compact set. Then using integration by part

$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f_n \phi' dx = - \int_{\mathbb R} f_n' \phi dx$$

First of all, as $||f_n - f||_{L^1} \to 0$, we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f_n \phi' dx \to \int_0^1 \phi' dx.$$

On the other hand, as $||f_n'||_{L^1} \to 0$,

$$-\int_{\mathbb R} f_n' \phi dx \to 0.$$

Thus we have

$$ \phi(1) - \phi(0) = \int_0^1 \phi' dx = 0.$$

But that is impossible as I can find $\phi$ with $\phi(0) \neq \phi(1)$. Thus such a sequence does not exist.

Remark: If you know some Sobolev space theory, the condition $||f_n - f||_{L^1} \to 0$ and $||f_n'||_{L^1} \to 0$ actually implies that $f$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1, 1}(\mathbb R)$. However we know that such a function has to be continuous. This again shows that such a sequence does not exist.